# Eigen expression template slower than manual loop for exponential

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2010, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to compute a sum of component-wise exponentials of an array. The array is an `Eigen::ArrayXd`, so I expect that Eigen's `exp` function will be optimized to the same code, or better, than a manual loop. Instead, I'm seeing that a manual loop is tens of percents faster. (In the example below, roughly 2.1 seconds for Eigen and 1.6 seconds for a manual loop.)

I'm not using any Eigen vectorization (SSE is disabled), MKL, or anything else special. This is just a default Visual Studio 2010 project, on the Release configuration, with Eigen 3.2.9 out-of-the-box. Specifying "Full Optimization" (/Ox) and "Favor fast code" (/Ot) makes no difference to the results.

I'm not knowledgeable enough to look at compiled code to understand what's happening - could anyone suggest why using Eigen directly might be slower, and how to coax it to produce the same performance as a manual loop?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const Eigen::ArrayXd xs(Eigen::ArrayXd::Random(1000000));
    Eigen::ArrayXd array_result(Eigen::ArrayXd::Zero(xs.size())), loop_result(Eigen::ArrayXd::Zero(xs.size()));

    {
        std::clock_t start_time = std::clock();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            const double b = i; // Values not important;
            array_result += exp(b * xs);
        }
        std::clock_t end_time = std::clock();
        std::cout << "Array time (seconds): " << static_cast<double>(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::clock_t start_time = std::clock();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
            const double b = i; // Values not important;
            for (Eigen::ArrayXd::Index i = 0; i < xs.size(); ++i) {
                loop_result[i] += exp(b * xs[i]);
            }
        }
        std::clock_t end_time = std::clock();
        std::cout << "Loop time (seconds): " << static_cast<double>(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `(b * xs).exp()`?

Comment: you defined `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` ?

Comment: @Avi, I did try `(b * xs).exp()` - the performance seemed identical. @kangshiyin, defining `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` doesn't seem to affect performance.

Comment: Try defining `NDEBUG` as well. Where are you defining `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE`? Is `/arch:AVX2` or "/arch:SSE" enabled in your project or is it `/arch:IA32` or `Not Set`?

Comment: `NDEBUG` is defined. No /arch value is set. I put `#define EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` immediately before `#include <Eigen/Dense>`.

Comment: No /arch defined defaults to SSE2, no? Explicitly define `/arch:IA32` to disable vectorization.

Comment: I take that back (kinda). VS doesn't seem to generate any different performance for the loop, from `/arch:IA32` through `/arch:AVX2`. I may go through the assembler later, just for fun.

Answer (score 2):

If you defined `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE`, both approaches will be almost the same in terms of C++ code, looping over each element of the array.

With `/Ox` and `/Ot`, you are telling your compiler to auto-vectorize the loops. But the loop generated by Eigen may be a little more complex/inefficient than the hand-written loop. Thus the performance is lower.

This also depends on the compiler. With compiler that do not auto-vectorize the loop, Eigen with `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` is almost same as the loop approach.

```
$ g++ -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -g -O3 -DNDEBUG eigen-speed.cpp -o eigen-speed && ./eigen-speed
Array time (seconds): 1.94
Loop time (seconds): 1.93
```

With Eigen vectorization enabled, Eigen performs better.

```
$ g++ -g -O3 -DNDEBUG eigen-speed.cpp -o eigen-speed && ./eigen-speed
Array time (seconds): 0.63
Loop time (seconds): 1.86
```

With compiler that auto-vectorize the loop, Eigen with `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` is still similar to the loop approach, but both vectorized by the compiler.

```
$ icpc -DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE -g -O3 -DNDEBUG eigen-speed.cpp -o eigen-speed && ./eigen-speed
Array time (seconds): 0.43
Loop time (seconds): 0.38
```

But when you enable Eigen vectorization,

```
$ icpc -g -O3 -DNDEBUG eigen-speed.cpp -o eigen-speed && ./eigen-speed
Array time (seconds): 0.7
Loop time (seconds): 0.36

$ icpc -mavx -g -O3 -DNDEBUG eigen-speed.cpp -o eigen-speed && ./eigen-speed
Array time (seconds): 0.32
Loop time (seconds): 0.18
```

suggesting that Eigen's vectorized exp() code is worse than compiler's auto-vectorized version, both for [Eigen's SSE version](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/arch_2SSE_2MathFunctions_8h_source.html#107) and [Eigen's AVX version](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/arch_2AVX_2MathFunctions_8h_source.html).

So you can see that VS is more like `icpc`.

Comment: It's very interesting that the vectorization may worsen performance, thanks. You say that the loop generated by Eigen may be less efficient that the handwritten loop (as seen in your third set of results, and mine) - could you please explain why that is? As far as I understand it, the expression templates are supposed to compile down to exactly the same code as the loop.

Comment: @GavinTruter It's a guess. I didn't check the Eigen code. Maybe it has a header and a tail before and after the main loop, to deal with the unaligned data, originally for vectorized code.